# Suggest an algorithm to measure how a node is connected to road network

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, network, road

I try to measure how well a node is connected to the rest of the network. If a city has a distant suburb connected with one sole road, it's connectedness is, say 1. If it's connected by 2 roads, it's 2, and so on. A point in the middle of the city is connected infinitely.

What are plugins or algorithms available?

I personally prefer open source solutions (QGIS, PostGIS, or python-based), but other options are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that ["node centrality"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) concepts, in the graph theoretic literature, may be helpful. Here is an [introduction to centrality measures](https://sites.google.com/site/networkanalysisacourse/schedule/an-introduction-to-centrality-measures) in graphs.

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify which GIS system you wish to implement your analyses so you could investigate the [sDNA](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/) which can be run in ArcGIS, python or AutoCAD.

Comment: As of now, sDNA (3.0 alpha release) also runs in QGIS.